# Jest unit testing 'expected mock functin to have been called last with, but it was not called'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am new to Jest unit test, I try to write a test but it keep saying `'expected mock function to have been called last with, but it was not called'` not sure where is the issue. Below is APIClient.js file which I wrote a API call and in the test file I have mock the data, it logged

```
Expected mock function to have been last called with:
```

`["/.../test1/...", {"argu4": "test4", "argu5": "test5", "name": [{"argu3": "test3"}, "argu2": "test2"]}, {"headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json", "guest": false, "locale": 'US'}}}]`

```
but it was not called.
```

APIClient.js

```
const { getLeapFrogHeaders } = require('...');

async myFunc(argu1, argu2, argu3, argu4, argu5) {
 const header = getLeapFrogHeaders();
 const requestBody = {
  name: [{ argu2, argu3}],
  argu4,
  argu5
 }

const response = await this.connector.patch(`/.../${argu1}/...`, requestBody, { headers });
return response.data;
}
```

APIClient.test.js

```
import APIClient from './';
import MockConnector from './';

const mockConnector = new MockConnector({});
const APIClient = new APIClient(mockConnector);

describe('APIClient test', () => {
 const headers = {
  'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
   guest: false,
   locale: 'US'
 };

 it('successfully create API', () =>{
  const requestBody = {
      name: [{ argu2: 'test2', argu3: 'test3'}],
      argu4: 'test4',
      argu5: 'test5'
     };
  const argu1 = 'test1';
  const spy = jest.spyOn(mockConnector, 'post');
  getLeapFrogHeaders.mockImplementation(() => headers);
  APIClient.myFunc(argu1, 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5');
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(`/.../${argu1}/...`, requestBody, { headers })

})
})
```

Comment: You are mocking `post` method, but the APIClient uses `patch` method. Please provide a minimal, complete code.